# Where is the break point in this ruby "loop do"?

Tags: ruby, loops

I am having trouble understanding where the breakpoint is in this do loop. How come the code just doesn't keep running?

```
def nearest_larger(arr, idx)
  diff = 1
  loop do
    left = idx - diff
    right = idx + diff

    if (left >= 0) && (arr[left] > arr[idx])
      return left
    elsif (right < arr.length) && (arr[right] > arr[idx])
      return right
    elsif (left < 0) && (right >= arr.length)
      return nil
    end

    diff += 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there are `return` statements.

Presumably at some point one of the conditions is met and the function exits.

Answer (score 2):

A `return` statement immediately stops a function, and returns the provided value.

Answer (score 2):

the `return` keyword is going to stop the running block once it's true